# plugin from github not successfully installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, plugins, github

When I place this in my base application html.haml file:

```
= javascript_include_tag :defaults, 'jquery-1.3.2.min', 'highcharts'
<!--[if IE]>
javascript_include_tag 'excanvas.compiled'
<![endif]-->
%script{:type => "text/javascript"}
$(document).ready(function() {
= yield :javascripts
});
```

I get a textual description of a graph that is supposed to appear visually:

$(document).ready(function() { var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({ chart: { margin: [50, 30, 0, 30], renderTo: 'pie-chart-container' }, credits: { text: 'Data provided by NETMARKETSHARE', enabled: true, href: 'http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser … px?qprid=3' }, legend: { style: {left: 'auto', right: '50px', top: '75px', bottom: 'auto' }, layout: 'vertical' }, plotOptions: { pie: {dataLabels: {color: 'white', enabled: true, formatter: function() { if (this.y > 15) return this.point.name; }, style: {font: '10pt Helvetica', textShadow: '#000000 1px 1px 2px' } } } }, series: [ {type: 'pie', data: [{y: 3.57, identifier: 'applewebkit', name: 'Safari'}, {y: 22.32, sliced: true, identifier: 'gecko', name: 'Firefox'}, {y: 56.9, identifier: 'msie', name: 'Internet Explorer'}, {y: 17.21, name: 'Other'}]} ], subtitle: { text: 'January 2010' }, title: { text: 'Browser Market Share' }, tooltip: { formatter: function() { return "" + this.point.name + ": " + this.y + " %"; } }, xAxis: { title: {text: '' } }, yAxis: { title: {text: '' } } }); });

Comment: Try `rake highcharts_rails:install --trace` to get the full error trace.
That'd be way more helpful than copy/pasting the list of files we can all see on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place that script in the layout or some other erb file.

The `application.js` is not being parsed so you can't use inline ruby in it (or any other file residing in the `public` directory.

Comment: Well, that helped with part of the question. But the chart still does not render, and it seems to be related to the ruby array and javascript trying to interpret it.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Do you use Firefox with Firebug (or similar), so that you can view any errors that come from the Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend contacting the project owner by filing an issue on the github project.

Comment: seconded:  there are search results of other people having the same problem.